# code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' when running Docker app

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm

I was able to build docker image but I'm not able to run it.

This the command I'm using to run

```
docker run coderpc/test-server
```

Below is the error I see in the console.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/test-server/src/app/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Here's the `package.json` configuration

```
{
  "name": "test-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3"
  },
}
```

**Dockerfile** configuration

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /fr-service/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Could anyone please point where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see there is no server file in your app folder